# Can't delete data from a database table using python placholder

Tags: python, mysql

```
def delete_data(self):
              connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",password="",database="stm")
              cur=connection.cursor()
              cur.execute("""Delete FROM students2
                            WHERE Roll_No=%s""",(
                                                 self.Roll_No_var.get()
                                                 ))

              connection.commit()
              self.fetch_data()
              self.clear()
              connection.close()
```

I created a function to delete data from a database table and called it with a delete button,but for some reason the data is not getting deleted,is thr any problem with query or maybe the python syntax is wrong??? please reply soon...

information of the program---

```
Database --stm,
table name --students2,
Roll_No --primary key,
Variable assign with Roll_No ---Roll_No_var
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong format, im new here, still learning!!

Comment: Print the SQL that you are sending to `cur.execute` and run it directly in `mysql`. Does it work then?

Comment: Creating a minimal reproducible example may help you and others solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example